# Efficiently converting a large pandas dataframe to a list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to convert the first 50 items in a large pandas dataframe into a list, that for each index in the dataframe the list would have the value. And even if the dataframe doesn't have any values in that index, I would like the list to have the value 0.
For example the pandas dataframe which looks like this:

```
ID      Count
0       20
1       50
2       60
4       90
5       20
.
49      65
.
9999999 60054
```

would be converted to the following list, with only the first 50 elements of the dataframe being relevant:

```
[20, 50, 60, 0, 90, 20......,65]
```

Note that at index=3 , the value in the list is 0, because the ID was not found in the pandas dataframe.

Comment: Is "ID" a column or the name of the index?

Comment: So does your result list have length 50, or 50 + number of added indices?

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly:

```
mylist = (df.iloc[:50].set_index('ID')
          .reindex(range(50), fill_value=0)['Count']
          .tolist())
```

Comment: `df.query('ID < 5').set_index('ID')['Count'].reindex(range(5), fill_value=0).tolist()`

Answer (score 2):

IIUC:

```
d = df.query('ID < 5')
m = dict(zip(*map(d.get, d)))
[m.get(i, 0) for i in range(5)]

[20, 50, 60, 0, 90]
```

Comment: My suggestion would be to use `m = dict(df.query("ID<5").values)`, instead mapping and zipping. Not sure this will be efficient than yours.

Comment: @SandeepKadapa, `.values` is a method call that will force all data to have the same `dtype`.  My approach guarantees to preserve the `dtype` of each column.  There are also efficiency related issues.  If `dtypes` are mixed, calling `.values` is expensive.  If not, then it is very efficient.